# how can i select only one file when i use the command migrate-mongo up

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

hello i'm trying to use the command `migrate-mongo up` in only one file but if i use the command `migrate-mongo up`  the command will up all the migrations files in pending , i need to select a specific file not all the files at the same time for example

```
migrate-mongo up 20160608155948-blacklist_the_beatles.js
```

this command is unknown command

i'm using this librery

https://github.com/seppevs/migrate-mongo#readme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`migrate-mongo` automatically runs on all migrations in the directory that have not been run. There are no options to change this behavior. Not knowing the use case here, you could potentially make a new migrations directory, or simply move the migrations you don't want to run out of the migrations directory.

If this is just a one-off use case, I'd recommend moving the migrations you don't need out of the directory, running `up` then moving them back. If this will be a persistent problem, I'd reconsider if migrations are really the right tool for the job, given that they are assumed to be run once, and in order.

Comment: do you know about other library like this but with the option to select a specific file ? because my problem is if i have 3 files and i need to "down" the file 2 i will start down the file 3 and finally the file 2 but i dont want to "down" the file 3 only the file 2 without affecting the file 3 do you know what can i do in that case ?

Comment: I'm not aware of another library - database migrations are usually written with the intent of being order dependent - and that's how `migrate-mongo` works.

Answer (score 0):

`mongo-migrate` does not have that option. You can use [db-mongo-migration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/db-mongo-migration). It supports specific file migration and also has an option for dry-run plus batch rollbacks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).